# How to fix throw new Error('Expected the listener to be a function.');

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
const { createStore } = require('redux');


const store = createStore((state={count:0},action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {
                count: state.count + action.incrementBy
            }
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return {
                count: state.count - 1
            }
        case 'SET':
            return {
                count: action.count
            }
        case 'RESET':
                return {
                    count:0
                }
        default:
            return state;
    }
});
const incrementBy = (counter = {incrementBy: 1}) => ({  
        type:'INCREMENT',
        incrementBy: typeof counter.incrementBy === 'number' ? counter.incrementBy : 1

});

store.subscribe(incrementBy({incrementBy: 5}));

store.dispatch(incrementBy());

store.dispatch({
    type : 'DECREMENT'
});

store.dispatch({
    type :'SET',
    count:101
});
store.dispatch({
    type : 'RESET'
});
```

Comment: You should provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
store.subscribe(incrementBy({incrementBy: 5}));
```

should be

```
store.dispatch(incrementBy({incrementBy: 5}));
```